# Configuring Ruby-on-rails created_at and updated_at dates time_zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, timezone

Rails stores created_at and updated_at timestamps in UTC time.

But I am using these fields to filter and store (and do a lot of other stuff with the records) based on these fields, so it's important that when I call created_at and updated_at attributes, I get timestamps in my time zone.

As told by the following two SO questions, I can do that by configuring the time zone in the environment.rb file.

However, that's now working for me.

Because I am fetching the records from the database, based on `created_at` fields (which are in UTC) so naturally wrong ones are coming out, and then I am displaying them, so the dates are displayed in UTC, again, not what I want.

Is there a way to change in what time-zones the rails stores the dates?

OR

Is there a workaround for how I can achieve the database-fetching and displaying, without making a call to Rails `object.created_at` attribute?

[Rails and timezone in created_at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556998/rails-and-timezone-in-created-at)

[Rails Time zone issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642571/rails-time-zone-issue)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The 'right way' to do this is for the records to be stored in UTC, then setting `Time.zone` in the cases you need it set to something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder why I even asked the question on this forum, because the workaround seemed to be pretty simple. But it did take me eight hours to reach it :)

1) While fetching records from the database and displaying them, I could simply do

```
select CONVERT_TZ(date) as date from table;
```

instead of doing

```
select date from table;
```

`CONVERT_TZ()` is a `mysql` specific function, so it worked for me. Not a universal solution though.

2) Secondly, when I had to fetch the records from a date range given in any other time-zone, I could do one of the two things.

One - I could replace `[user-entered-date] 00:00:00` with `[user-entered-date] 07:00:00` for the date-range's starting point and `[user-entered-date] 59:59:59` with `[user-entered-date + 1.day] 07:00:00` for the range's ending point. Note this would require me to use DateTime objects instead of using Date objects.

Two - In the `where` clause, I could do

```
CONVERT_TZ(registrations.created_at) <= [user/entered/date]
```

instead of

```
(registrations.created_at) <= [user/entered/date]
```